# How to construct hibernate query using dynamic inputs?

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a situation where I want to construct a hibernate query where my API accepts dynamic input.

As in, Client can specify if they want to pass {column1} or {column1, column2} or {column1,column2, column3} as input to API.

if they pass only column1, I will query with column1. If they pass {column1, column2}, I will query with column1 & column2. and so on...

Any suggestions on constructing such query in hibernate?

Comment: if columns are simple attributes, it's easy to use QBE - http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-query-example-qbe - but if columns are foreign keys to other entities, then you're doomed

Answer (score 0):

Look about [Hibernate Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

For some dummy example you can write it like;

```
public List<User> getAllUsersForConditions(String firstName, String lastName, int age) throws RepositoryException {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
    if (firstName != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("firstName", firstName));
    }
    if (lastName != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("lastName", lastName));
    }
    if (lastName != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("age", age));
    }
    return (List<User>) criteria.list();
}
```

Also, if you have simple query like upper example, then you can use [Query By Example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples) like @Leo said.

But if you have complex structure, then this approach with Criteria will work. If your search is even more complex then you should use [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Hope it helps.